# How to get rid of "An unknown compilation problem occurred" Maven error?

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci

### Context

Edit: note it is quite hard to share my `pom.xml` file since it is 800+ lines and around 50+ other modules with they own `pom.xml` files too, on which you can add some confidential information in some of these.

I have Maven commands run on a GitLab CI like this:

```
my_job:
  ...
  script:
    - mvn clean install -ntp -DskipTests
  after_script:
    - mvn -e -X -ntp -f ".\path\to\pom.xml" test -Dtest="MyClass#myTest"
  ...
```

The whole job passes whereas for second command at some point (changing project branch with too much changes to see what can be guilty of this) I started getting `An unknown compilation problem occurred` error and no log at all of `MyClass.myTest`, see full stacktrace at end of this post.

Also note that when I run `MyClass.myTest` from IntelliJ (with "run" button at left of test) it passes without any issue.

### Question

Anyone knows why I got this error and how to get rid of it ?

Note I saw something with removal of `<compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>` in `maven-compiler-plugin` declaration but I don't have `compilerArgument` at all, other stuff I found was too specific to their context.

### Full stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project bla-bla: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project bla-bla: Compilation failure
An unknown compilation problem occurred

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
An unknown compilation problem occurred

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1310)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: Share your Pom.xml

Comment: I got to go now but I'll see on Monday if I can since it very big (800+ lines) and contains confidential stuff.

Comment: Then reduce it to the simplest possible showing the error

Comment: Thanks, I'll try but this is in a project with 50+ modules (then 50+ pom.xml) around the one that fails that can have an impact on it.

Comment: This is the javac invocation failing. Consider enabling full debug log or even attach a debugger so you can see what happens. First line of attack is ensuring all maven plugins support the version of Java you use.

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately this works when running locally on my computer but fails on GitLab pipelines where we got no hand on any debugger. But I'll check maven plugins just in case.

Comment: Talk to your Gitlab person.  It is possible to remote debug Maven with the proper invocation even when running inside Gitlab.  That might be needed here.

Comment: OK thanks I'll to that.

Comment: You may also want to ask other Senior Java developers at your workplace, because this is most likely a bad flag to javac.