# How to get rid of 'groupId' with value '...' does not match a valid id pattern Maven error?

Tags: maven, gitlab

### Context

While trying to figure out [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78128410/how-to-get-rid-of-an-unknown-compilation-problem-occurred-maven-error) I got this another error after adding `-X` to the second command, here is the context again with different info according to new question.

I have Maven commands run on a GitLab CI like this:

```
my_job:
  ...
  script:
    - mvn clean install -ntp -DskipTests
  after_script:
    - mvn -e -X -ntp -f ".\path\to\pom.xml" test -Dtest="MyClass#myTest"
  ...
```

The whole job passes whereas for second command, only when I use `-X` (then I'm not sure it is relevant to chase it... at least having a cleaner project maybe), I got following error (I obviously changed the name just keeping same amount of letters, `-` and `/`):

```
[ERROR] 'groupId' with value 'aa/bbb/cccc-dddddddd/eeeeeeeee-fff-gggggg/hhhhhhhhhhh' does not match a valid id pattern. @
```

However in corresponding `pom.xml` file the `groupId` should matche regexp checking its validity (see [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35631066/11159476)), except if I missed something else:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>aa.bbb.cccc-dddddddd.eeeeeeeee-fff-gggggg.hhhhhhhhhhh</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_dependency</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>xsd</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

### Question

Anyone knows why I got this error and how to get rid of it ?